# Comparison of tidy up and tidied up

Tags: passive-voice

What is wrong with this sentence?

If you keep your room tidy up, it is easier to find things.

Comment: I think the actual question you want to ask is about how "[keep](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep)" in the sense "to (cause to) stay in a particular place or condition" is used. If you know that "keep" when used this way is followed by a noun and an adjective, then the rest should be obvious.

Comment: You can't use "tidy up" as an adjective. Just use "If you keep your room tidy ...".  Remove the word "up".

Answer (score 3):

Tidy can be a verb - *you must tidy your room.* You can add 'up' if you want - *you must tidy up your room.*

Tidy can also be an adjective - *you must keep your room tidy.*

You can only add 'up' to the verb. Not to the adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The present tense form is not used in that construction, when one is describing a state of things. Instead a past participle is used. This is not unique to "*tidy*".  Consider:

> - If you keep your room **clean** up, it is easier to find things. [image: Red X, indicting an incorrect form]
> - If you keep your room **cleaned** up, it is easier to find things. [image: Green check-mark, indicating a valid form]

Or consider an example that is not as close to the original:

> - The concrete is not done until it has been smooth off. [image: Red X, indicting an incorrect form]
> - The concrete is not done until it has been smoothed off. [image: Green check-mark, indicating a valid form]

or, without using a phrasal verb:

> - If the mirror is polish, the image is clearer. [image: Red X, indicting an incorrect form]
> - If the mirror is polished, the image is clearer. [image: Green check-mark, indicating a valid form]